# Is there any way to change the "ok" in message dialog according to the language in Applet?

Tags: java, swing, localization, applet, awt

Actually in my project there is a need to change everything accordingly with the language selection. I use this to show the message dialog

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, PCBString.strErrorMsg [IP_INVALID_OCTED_INDEX][objTable.chDispLang]);
```

It will show message dialog with title "message" and button "ok". I found overloaded version of to change the title "message" accordingly with the language i.e:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, PCBString.strErrorMsg [IP_INVALID_OCTED_INDEX][objTable.chDispLang],"mesanje",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

But now i want to change the "ok" button with the language.

Comment: Thanks for editing...Bondax..

Comment: You're probably looking for message bundles.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, "Oh-kay" being used on the button:

```
 Object[] options = {"Oh-kay"};
 int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
      "Die Message pour vous",
      "window title", 
      JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
      JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
      null,
      options,
      options[0]);
```

Comment: yeah i have tried with this. But that is working partially what i want. May be i have to put the condition. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I didn't have full information, so what do you expect?